# Does Microsoft.Azure.Devices Auto-Retry Policy work on Transient Errors?

Tags: azure, amqp, azure-iot-hub, exponential-backoff

I am using Microsoft.Azure.Devices nuget package to send packets onto the IOT Hub device over amqp. At times when there is a connectivity issue, I receive 'No such host is known'. I have default retry policy (exponential-backoff) enabled on my client. As this is a transient error, would auto retry policy work or would I have to write custom logic to retry after such exception.

Comment: Looks like you everything set up to test this out! Can you include the steps you took already to confirm/deny if the auto retry works?

Comment: The default policy retries with exponential backoff when Azure Event Hub returns a transient error. Default retry policy for Event Hubs is to retry up to 9 times with an exponential back-off time of up to 30 seconds. Please see this document for Retry Policies https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-reliability-features-in-sdks#retry-policy-apis.

Comment: Matthijs I disabled the amqp port and received connection error, then I enabled amqp port and the client started sending messages that failed. I wasn't sure it worked when I deployed on a server, because after some time, the client did not responded. I'll test it out further.

Comment: @NiharikaMoola-MT yeah that's what I read as well, will test further to confirm.